# copying specific entries from table based on "name" (find function) vba

Tags: vba, excel, find

I have a code that's intended to:
 1) Find a *name* from a table using a searchbox
 2) Copy cells in the row with the *name* on to another sheet
 3) This should work for all entries in the table associated with this name.

Code sample:

```
Sub Printout()
Dim LR2 As Long
Dim c As Variant
Dim txt As Variant

c = InputBox("Enter Last Name")
txt = CStr(c)
Sheets("B").Select
Sheets("B").Range("K3").Value = txt

Sheets("A").Select
Sheets("A").Columns(2).Find(What:=txt, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True).Activate
LR2 = Sheets("A").Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("A").Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2), Cells(LR2, 10)).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets("B").Range("A2:J2")


End Sub
```

Problem:
Currently, the code doesn't just copy the specific name from the searchbox input, but all entries under the name as well. Ie if "Johnson" is entry 3, 6, and 11, I want columns 2 to 10 for those three rows. Currently it finds the first entry and seem to copy everything in columns 2 to 10 underneath it. Can someone please help me troubleshoot this code so that I can make it do what I want?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks the LR2 variable should apply to sheet B rather than A as otherwise you will continually be overwriting the copied cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be what youre after. Season to taste but itll do what you want

```
Private Sub derp()
    Dim this As String
    this = InputBox("Enter Last Name")
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rcell As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim that As Variant

    lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:a40")
    For Each rcell In rng.Cells
        If rcell.Value <> vbNullString Then
            If rcell.Value = this Then
                that = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & rcell.Row & ":H" & rcell.Row)
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & lastrow & ":H" & lastrow).Value2 = that
                lastrow = lastrow + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next rcell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems to work (although inexplicably transports to row 10 and down on Sheet B but that's brobably due to something I did on that sheet and no biggie)

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess

```
Sub Printout()

Dim LR2 As Long
Dim c As Variant
Dim txt As Variant
Dim r As Range
Dim s As String

c = InputBox("Enter Last Name")
txt = CStr(c)

Sheets("B").Range("K3").Value = txt

With Sheets("A")
    Set r = .Columns(2).Find(What:=txt, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not r Is Nothing Then
        s = r.Address
        Do
            LR2 = Sheets("B").Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
            .Range(.Cells(r.Row, 2), .Cells(r.Row, 10)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("B").Range("A" & LR2)
            Set r = .Columns(2).FindNext(r)
        Loop While r.Address <> s
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is sometimes problematic to work with code, that is not created by you. In your case, you want to select and copy the cells, which you have found in column 2.

If you take a look at this code and edit it a bit, you would be able to do it.

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Sub Printout()

    Dim txt         As Variant
    Dim rngUnion    As Range
    Dim rngCell     As Range

    txt = "vi"

    With ActiveSheet
        For Each rngCell In .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(9, 1))
            If InStr(1, rngCell, txt) Then
                If rngUnion Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngUnion = .Range(.Cells(rngCell.Row, 2), .Cells(rngCell.Row, 5))
                Else
                    Set rngUnion = Union(rngUnion, .Range(.Cells(rngCell.Row, 2), .Cells(rngCell.Row, 5)))
                End If
            End If
        Next rngCell
    End With

    rngUnion.Select

End Sub
```

Your ActiveSheet should like this:
[image]

What the code does:

- It loops through the Cells from A1 to A9.
- If it finds `vi` in one of those cells, it adds 4 cells of the same row to a union - `rngUnion`
- At the end it selects a union, just to show you which one is it. You can copy the selection or copy the range, without selecting it.

Good luck, have fun!